# user-defined mixed listing query in sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

suppose that,
I have a db which is included USR_NR field (integer type). and I know all datas in field. no any surprises nr.

```
USR_NR : 1,3,4,7,9,12,44,13,78
```

I need to listed this field as mixed like 1,78,44,9,7,3,12,4,13
there is no rule for listing. I want to sort the way I wanted.

I tried with `ORDER BY` but how can I advance ?
I can not use `ASC` , `DESC`

```
SELECT * FROM DB ORDER BY ?
```

could you help me for this ?

Comment: or you can add  your own numeric field, and fill it with values, which would be use for sorting

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a form where you can set a *priority number* for each record using a function like this:

```
' Set the priority order of a record relative to the other records of a form.
'
' The table/query bound to the form must have an updatable numeric field for
' storing the priority of the record. Default value of this should be Null.
'
' Requires:
'   A numeric, primary key, typical an AutoNumber field.
'
' 2018-08-31. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Sub RowPriority( _
    ByRef TextBox As Access.TextBox, _
    Optional ByVal IdControlName As String = "Id")

    ' Error codes.
    ' This action is not supported in transactions.
    Const NotSupported      As Long = 3246
    Dim Form                As Access.Form
    Dim Records             As DAO.Recordset

    Dim RecordId            As Long
    Dim NewPriority         As Long
    Dim PriorityFix         As Long
    Dim FieldName           As String
    Dim IdFieldName         As String

    Dim Prompt              As String
    Dim Buttons             As VbMsgBoxStyle
    Dim Title               As String

    On Error GoTo Err_RowPriority

    Set Form = TextBox.Parent

    If Form.NewRecord Then
        ' Will happen if the last record of the form is deleted.
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' Save record.
        Form.Dirty = False
    End If

    ' Priority control can have any Name.
    FieldName = TextBox.ControlSource
    ' Id (primary key) control can have any name.
    IdFieldName = Form.Controls(IdControlName).ControlSource

    ' Prepare form.
    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    Form.Repaint
    Form.Painting = False

    ' Current Id and priority.
    RecordId = Form.Controls(IdControlName).Value
    PriorityFix = Nz(TextBox.Value, 0)
    If PriorityFix <= 0 Then
        PriorityFix = 1
        TextBox.Value = PriorityFix
        Form.Dirty = False
    End If

    ' Disable a filter.
    ' If a filter is applied, only the filtered records
    ' will be reordered, and duplicates might be created.
    Form.FilterOn = False

    ' Rebuild priority list.
    Set Records = Form.RecordsetClone
    Records.MoveFirst
    While Not Records.EOF
        If Records.Fields(IdFieldName).Value <> RecordId Then
            NewPriority = NewPriority + 1
            If NewPriority = PriorityFix Then
                ' Move this record to next lower priority.
                NewPriority = NewPriority + 1
            End If
            If Nz(Records.Fields(FieldName).Value, 0) = NewPriority Then
                ' Priority hasn't changed for this record.
            Else
                ' Assign new priority.
                Records.Edit
                    Records.Fields(FieldName).Value = NewPriority
                Records.Update
            End If
        End If
        Records.MoveNext
    Wend

    ' Reorder form and relocate record position.
    ' Will fail if more than one record is pasted in.
    Form.Requery
    Set Records = Form.RecordsetClone
    Records.FindFirst "[" & IdFieldName & "] = " & RecordId & ""
    Form.Bookmark = Records.Bookmark

PreExit_RowPriority:
    ' Enable a filter.
    Form.FilterOn = True
    ' Present form.
    Form.Painting = True
    DoCmd.Hourglass False

    Set Records = Nothing
    Set Form = Nothing

Exit_RowPriority:
    Exit Sub

Err_RowPriority:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case NotSupported
            ' Will happen if more than one record is pasted in.
            Resume PreExit_RowPriority
        Case Else
            ' Unexpected error.
            Prompt = "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
            Buttons = vbCritical + vbOKOnly
            Title = Form.Name
            MsgBox Prompt, Buttons, Title

            ' Restore form.
            Form.Painting = True
            DoCmd.Hourglass False
            Resume Exit_RowPriority
    End Select

End Sub
```

It is explained in detail in my article which includes a demo as well:

[Sequential Rows in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33069/Sequential-Rows-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

If you don't have an account, browse for the link: Read the full article.

Code is also on **GitHub**: [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `instr()`:

```
order by instr(",1,78,44,9,7,3,12,4,13,", "," & USR_NR & ",")
```

Or, somewhat more verbosely, use `switch`:

```
order by switch(USR_NR = 1,  1,
                USR_NR = 78, 2,
                USR_NR = 44, 3,
                . . .
               )
```

Comment: I think the `instr` method would need to be something like `order by instr(",1,78,44,9,7,3,12,4,13,", "," & USR_NR & ",")` otherwise `7` will be sorted based on the `7` in `78`. Nice idea though.

Comment: @LeeMac . . . I agree.  Thank you.